# How to Contextualise Social Trust?

Tags: trust

A Meta-Analytical Review in [Ethnic Diversity and Social Trust](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-polisci-052918-020708) says the following:

> On average, social trust is thus lower in more ethnically diverse contexts. That being said, the rather modest size of the relationship implies that apocalyptic claims regarding the severe threat of ethnic diversity for social trust in contemporary societies are exaggerated.

Later the authors go on to quantify it as a "partial correlation of −0.0256" or "a 0.66% increase in the aggregate". While the number is modestly small this means nothing to anyone reading it. My hope is that by contextualising it with other experiences involving social trust the reader will be able to conceptualise a baseline scale for -0.025 to exist within.

For example, I found a study of [Homeownership and Social Trust in Neighbors](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1540-6040.2012.01416.x) that found the social trust coefficient of −0.169 existed between Neighbours when they have kids.

Would that be a fair comparison to make to help contextualise the effects of ethnic diversity and are they any further examples that I could use?